# Docker OS/Arch does not match uname

Tags: docker

After installing Docker on a raspberry pi 4 following the official raspberry pi os docker install [guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/raspberry-pi-os/) the docker version is the following

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:37 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm
 Context:           default
```

But my name OS/Arch is given as aarch64 which is as far as I know identical to arm64. My question now is why the docker engine is not of arch arm64? Because I require to run an arm64 docker image. Thanks for helping out

uname result:

```
aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your os is 32bit and use 64bit kernel? I suggest you check your os version use this command:

```
getconf LONG_BIT
```

if the result display 32, you should reinstall pi os to 64bit os like bookworm follow this site, [Install using Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#install-using-imager), and then reinstall docker engine, see it if this will help. Otherwise will show 64.

Docker version:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:31:32 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Context:           default
```

Comment: Yup that was it thanks